# Por que otros arreglos toman el valor de otro

Tags: c++, array

estoy intentando hacer un programa que realiza el ordenamiento de números, tengo una función que genera los valores de un arreglo de tamaño 10.
En total tengo tres arreglos, pero al imprimirlos los otros dos arreglos toman los valores del arreglo que se genero con la función(los valores se generan de forma aleatoria).

Como nota los otros dos arreglos tienen valores definidos.

Aca dejo una parte de código.

```
int a[10] = {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; 
int b[10] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}; 
int c[10]; // Los valores se generan de forma aleatoria 

generaArregloAleatorio(c);

  //MERGESORT
  cout << "Mergesort\n" << endl;
  cout << "Mejor caso - Arreglo ordenado\n" << endl;
  cout << "Arreglo antes de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(a);
  mergeSort(a, tiempo);
  cout << "\nArreglo despues de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(a);
  cout << "\nTiempo de ejecucion para el mejor caso " << float(tiempo)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " segundos."<< endl;
  cout << "\n" << endl;

  cout << "Peor caso - Arreglo desordenado\n" << endl;
  cout << "Arreglo antes de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(b);
  mergeSort(b, tiempo);
  cout << "\nArreglo despues de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(b);
  cout << "\nTiempo de ejecucion para el peor caso " << float(tiempo)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " segundos."<< endl;
  cout << "\n" << endl;

  cout << "Caso promedio - Arreglo ordenado de forma aleatoria\n" << endl;
  cout << "Arreglo antes de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(c);
  mergeSort(c, tiempo);
  cout << "\nArreglo despues de ordenar" << endl;
  imprimeArreglo(c);
  cout << "\nTiempo de ejecucion para el caso promedio " << float(tiempo)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " segundos."<< endl;
  cout << "\n" << endl;
```

Comment: Faltan las funciones imprimeArreglo y mergeSort

Comment: Se imprime antes de ordenar y los valores que toman los indices son siempre los que contiene c(arreglo llenado de forma aleatoria)

Comment: creo que no me he explicado... el código que has puesto, por si mismo, no es dañino. El problema por tanto debe estar en una de las funciones que utilizas. Si no están esas funciones, no podemos darte una respuesta